# The name 'Initial' is used by an existing migration

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, abp

I have this configurations:
ABP Framework: 4.2.1
User Interface: MVC
Database Provider: EF Core / PostgreSQL
Exception: The name 'Initial' is used by an existing migration.

When I start a new project, and run the command dotnet run in DbMigrator I got the error: The name 'Initial' is used by an existing migration.

[image: configuration]

In the migrations folder, I only have a Initial migrations

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the `DbMigrator` call `dotnet ef migrations add Initial` everytime? Without deleting the existing migration you can't create a new one (called `Initial`). Check your `DbMigrator`, maybe show some code.

Comment: @BenceL I tried to delete the existing migrations, but I got the same error =/

Comment: Did you delete it via `dotnet ef migrations remove`? Or just deleted it? You should use the tool.

Comment: @BenceL , yes! via CLI ;)

Comment: It must be such an obvious mistake, but I can't see it (It's making me crazyyyy...). Could you show me your `DbMigrator` code? At least part of it and what it does. Are you sure that's the correct directory and `DbMigrator` doesn't create it at a different place (mistakes happen). Sorry for the obvious questions but I have no idea how to proceed with this problem. If your (or your company's) policy allows it, it could be a great idea to upload it to github, so I can test it (It's unlikely you can upload it, but worth a try).

Comment: One other way could be to rename the command in `DbMigrator`, it's worth a try i guess. Call the migration `WorkPlease` or something and see if it works.

Comment: Also I'm wondering why you'd want to create a migration with the same name as an already existing one? Are you trying to override to old one?

Comment: @BenceL, can you make a test?
Create a project using this template: https://abp.io/get-started

Like this:
https://imgur.com/a/mVGWrum

And than try to run the DbMigrator, please ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I can give you a definite answer, but here it comes. First or all, I didn't even realise that this ABP framework gives you a full template to work on. I created one with the parameters you've given me in the comments.

As I looked at the code, the `DbMigrator` calls the method `<ProjectName>DbMigrationService.AddInitialMigration()`, this is called when the framework can't find the `Migrations` folder (and the migration project exists but it's generated by the framework so it exists). This method didn't do anything for me (maybe not enough permissions I don't know), but in its essence it just calls an `abp` cli command to generate the first migration. So I ran it by hand.

[image: abp command create initial migration]

This ran successfully (as I think in your case). If I tried to run it a second time, It would obviously fail. This command should only be used for the `Initial` migration (basically the framework has predefined tables and generates the migration for it).

I ran the `DbMigrator` a second time (debugged it actually) and saw that the `AddInitialMigration` is not called for me this time (and this is correct). I did a little google search `abp create new migration` first result, scrolled down a lot (you can just search `Add-Migration` and read around the first match). The documentation states an example (I didn't read it obviously), but it had one essential sentence. `Now, you can add a new EF Core database migration using the standard Add-Migration command...`, this sentence to me states that new migrations have to be created via the `dotnet cli`. So then I created it (please excuse the version warning).

[image: dotnet ef migrations add PleaseWork]

[image: files after 2nd migration]

Then I ran the `DbMigrator` via `dotnet run` and voila the new migration was in the database.

[image: sqlite migrations applied screenshot]

So the **conclusion** from me: This is a fancy framework and I love code generation, but this is just too much for me, It generates so much stuff that a lot of people without years of experience will just get lost in.

So then how can you generate a migration?

1. Modify your `Context` class(es) and entities the way you want.
2. Create the migration by hand via the `dotnet ef migrations add <migration_name>`, make sure you are in the `<ProjectName>.EntityFrameworkCore.DbMigrations` folder.
3. Run the `DbMigrator` via the `dotnet run` command.

I hope this helps. :D

**EDIT:** If your `DbMigrator` still fails, then I suggest you Debug the code, and look at the command it tries to execute:

```
var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, $"{argumentPrefix} \"abp create-migration-and-run-migrator \"{GetDbMigrationsProjectFolderPath()}\"\"");
```

procStartInfo (it's line 143 for me), will contain the actual command, `abp create-migration ...` look at the path It selects and clear the `Migrations` folder from that folder, and then try again.

Comment: thank you for your great explanation!
I created a video to illustrate my problem: https://youtu.be/Vk3d_d4yFRs
Take a look please ;)

Comment: I think something is wrong there, as you can see the `Creating initial migration` was printed out twice. I don't know what causes this, but I don't think it should be a problem (as I saw correctly the `Initial` migration was correctly created). If you run it once, and run it again without deleting the file do you get the same error? Also, please try using an external terminal, not the one in Rider.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem on Ubuntu. The reason turned out to be the case sensitivity of Linux. In the file `*DbMigrationService.cs`, changing "migrations" to "Migrations" will make it works.